# How to perform GUI task in Java

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, ide

I am moving to Java from C#, and for  my curiosity I like to ask question, in C# adding UI objects was drag and drop task and also changing and setting the object property was easy.
How to do the GUI tasks in Java? are they like C#?
and which IDE to use for it, as I have used Visual Studio 2008 for C#.

Thanks

Comment: The main reason to code Java GUIs differently is that they use LayoutManagers to ensure the GUI works on a variety of platforms (PLAFS, screen resolutions etc.).  While I avoid GUI designers, an expert using a GUI designer (at least the NetBeans GUI designer) can incorporate Java layouts.  Don't fall into the mistake of using XYLayout (or whatever they are called) or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gui Building: NetBeans is very common.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html

Personally I build my own, but they aren't complicated so I can get away with that.

Java development in general: Eclipse is very popular. It's what I use.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is good for GUI as it has a builder. However, I would strongly recommend coding it yourself. Its not too complicated a task. Be aware of threading issues though, learn some simple concepts like Event Dispatch Thread, Swingworker, etc. I would suggest embarking on a small project to get a hang of it. Otherwise, Sun tutorials are highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> How to do the GUI tasks in Java?

[Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

> are they like C#?

Yes!

> and which IDE to use for it, as I have used Visual Studio 2008 for C#.

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)

More: [Java GUI Alternatives](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/misc/80gui-generator.html)